# ionic $state doesn't trigger socket emit

Tags: node.js, sockets, ionic-framework

```
.controller('order_completed', function($scope,$http,$state,socket) {

    var order = localStorage.getItem('order');

    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
          socket.emit('order', order);
    });

});
```

not sure why I need to **refresh** then only can see the emit got executed. I use $state.go('order') to come to this page.

Comment: Please provide code for socket service

Comment: @AdityaSingh http://pastebin.com/2GBeG9Yb