# using socket io for mobile app and web

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, ionic-framework

I want to do this

1. a user placed an order on mobile app
2. in the seller's dashboard (web), it show an instant order

I've done the normal API, means without socket.io, the seller have to refresh the dashboard in order to see the if any order is placed.

Yesterday I play around with socket.io, I'm stuck. I'm able to send something from my mobile app (cilent) to my server (node.js), but I don't know what to do with the data received.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  io.on('connection', function(client) { 
            client.on('order', function(data) {
                console.log(data); //real time data from mobile app
                //I have the data but what to do here?
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Too broad question

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly maybe u can answer this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089399/ionic-state-doesnt-trigger-socket-emit